# Android 11 image saving issue

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap, android-11

The below function was working properly in android 10 but after updating to android 11 it does not work in apache cordova-phonegap

```
function clickPhoto(source) {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 20,destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI});
};
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem.

On Samsung Galaxy XCover Pro worked fine on Android 10, after udpating to Andorid 11 it doesn't work anymore. When calling navigator.camera.getPicture a .jpg file is created but the file is empty (0 KB).

Answer (score -1):

Please check this. Worked for me.

> I resolved the issue by changing the source code in
> CameraLauncher.java file, the issue is that android 11 does not allow
> access to URIs created from URI.fromFile from one application to
> another. For example, in the performcrop method we are generating a
> `croppedUri = Uri.fromFile(createCaptureFile(this.encodingType,`
> `System.currentTimeMillis() + ""));`
>
> and passing it to other activity therefore the receiving application
> will not have access to the croppedUri and throws an error like Access
> Denied or Editing is not allowed for this image.
>
> So in order to resolve that we need to create a URI from
> FileProvider.getUriForFile().
>
> I know it may sound silly. but replace with the following in
> performCrop method solved it for me.
>
> `croppedUri = picUri;`
>
> It worked for me on Android 10 and 11.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/issues/718#issuecomment-864517005